# how can i call this news-ticker in multiple places on the same page?

Tags: jquery, news-ticker

can someone how me how can i get this ticker be used for 2 different places in the same page? when i currently try the first works but the second one has no effect.

I am not getting any clue as jq is new to me.

here is the ticker.js

```
(function($){

    $.fn.tickerme = function(options) {

        var opts = $.extend( {}, $.fn.tickerme.defaults, options );

        return this.each(function(){

            var ticker = $(this);
            // SVG definitions for the play/pause/previous/next controls:
            var control_definitions = '<svg display="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="224" height="32" viewBox="0 0 224 32"><defs><g id="icon-play"><path class="path1" d="M6 4l20 12-20 12z"></path></g><g id="icon-pause"><path class="path1" d="M4 4h10v24h-10zM18 4h10v24h-10z"></path></g><g id="icon-prev"><path class="path1" d="M18 5v10l10-10v22l-10-10v10l-11-11z"></path></g><g id="icon-next"><path class="path1" d="M16 27v-10l-10 10v-22l10 10v-10l11 11z"></path></g></defs></svg>';
            var control_styles = '<style type="text/css">#ticker_container{width:100%}#newscontent{float:left}#news{display:none}#controls{float:right;height:16px}.icon{display:inline-block;width:16px;height:16px;fill:'+opts.control_colour+'}.icon:hover{fill:'+opts.control_rollover+'}</style>';
            // Array to contain news contents:
            var contents = [];
            var position = -1;
            var timer;

            init();

            /* Initialise */

            function init() {

                // Hide all:
                $(ticker).hide();

                // Create the buttons:
                $('body').prepend(control_definitions).prepend(control_styles);

                var controls = '<div id="ticker_container">';
                controls += '<div id="newscontent"><div id="news"></div></div>';
                controls += '<div id="controls">';
                controls += '<a href="#" id="pause_trigger"><svg class="icon icon-pause" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-pause"></use></svg></a>';
                controls += '<a href="#" id="play_trigger" style="display:none"><svg class="icon icon-play" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-play"></use></svg></a>';
                controls += '<a href="#" id="prev_trigger"><svg class="icon icon-prev" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-prev"></use></svg></a>';
                controls += '<a href="#" id="next_trigger"><svg class="icon icon-next" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-next"></use></svg></a>';
                controls += '</div>';
                controls += '</div>';
                $(controls).insertAfter(ticker);

                // Load up the array:
                $(ticker).children().each(function(i){
                    contents[i] = ($(this).html());
                });

                load_container();
            }

            /* load_container */

            function load_container() {

                if (position == (contents.length - 1)) {
                    position = 0;
                } else {
                    position++;
                }       
                // Fade out the current item, replace it with the next one, and fade it in:
                if (opts.type == 'fade') {
                    $('#news').fadeOut(opts.fade_speed,function(){
                        $('#newscontent').html('<div id="news">'+contents[position]+'</div>');
                        $('#news').fadeIn(opts.fade_speed);
                    });
                }
                timer = setTimeout(load_container,opts.duration);
            }

            /* Control functions */

            $('a#pause_trigger').click(function() {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                $(this).hide();
                $('#play_trigger').show();
                return false;
            });

            $('a#play_trigger').click(function(){
                load_container();
                $(this).hide();
                $('#pause_trigger').show();
                return false;
            });

            $('a#prev_trigger').click(function(){
                if (position == 0) {
                    position = (contents.length - 1);
                } else {
                    position--;
                }
                $('#newscontent').html('<div id="news" style="display:block">'+contents[position]+'</div>');
                if (opts.auto_stop) $('a#pause_trigger').trigger('click');
                return false;
            });

            $('a#next_trigger').click(function(){
                if (position == (contents.length - 1)) {
                    position = 0;
                } else {
                    position++;
                }
                $('#newscontent').html('<div id="news" style="display:block">'+contents[position]+'</div>');
                if (opts.auto_stop) $('a#pause_trigger').trigger('click');
                return false;
            });

        });

    };

    $.fn.tickerme.defaults = {
        fade_speed: 500,
        duration: 30000,
        auto_stop: true,
        type: 'fade',
        control_colour: '#333333',
        control_rollover: '#666666'
    };

}(jQuery));
```

and this is how it's called

```
 <div id="ticker_wrap">
        <div id="ticker" >
            <?php
            $qts = $db->query("SELECT * FROM quotes ORDER BY id ASC");
            foreach($qts as $row) {
            ?>
            <div class="quotes">
            <?php echo $row['planet_quote']; ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

would really appreciate your help and time you have given to help me out.

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.tickerme = function(options) {

    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.tickerme.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {

      var ticker = $(this);
      // SVG definitions for the play/pause/previous/next controls:
      var control_definitions = '<svg display="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="224" height="32" viewBox="0 0 224 32"><defs><g id="icon-play"><path class="path1" d="M6 4l20 12-20 12z"></path></g><g id="icon-pause"><path class="path1" d="M4 4h10v24h-10zM18 4h10v24h-10z"></path></g><g id="icon-prev"><path class="path1" d="M18 5v10l10-10v22l-10-10v10l-11-11z"></path></g><g id="icon-next"><path class="path1" d="M16 27v-10l-10 10v-22l10 10v-10l11 11z"></path></g></defs></svg>';
      var control_styles = '<style type="text/css">#ticker_container{width:100%}#newscontent{float:left}#news{display:none}#controls{float:right;height:16px}.icon{display:inline-block;width:16px;height:16px;fill:' + opts.control_colour + '}.icon:hover{fill:' + opts.control_rollover + '}</style>';
      // Array to contain news contents:
      var contents = [];
      var position = -1;
      var timer;

      init();

      /* Initialise */

      function init() {

        // Hide all:
        $(ticker).hide();

        // Create the buttons:
        $('body').prepend(control_definitions).prepend(control_styles);

        var controls = '<div id="ticker_container">';
        controls += '<div id="newscontent"><div id="news"></div></div>';
        controls += '<div id="controls">';
        controls += '<a href="#" id="pause_trigger"><svg class="icon icon-pause" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-pause"></use></svg></a>';
        controls += '<a href="#" id="play_trigger" style="display:none"><svg class="icon icon-play" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-play"></use></svg></a>';
        controls += '<a href="#" id="prev_trigger"><svg class="icon icon-prev" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-prev"></use></svg></a>';
        controls += '<a href="#" id="next_trigger"><svg class="icon icon-next" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-next"></use></svg></a>';
        controls += '</div>';
        controls += '</div>';
        $(controls).insertAfter(ticker);

        // Load up the array:
        $(ticker).children().each(function(i) {
          contents[i] = ($(this).html());
        });

        load_container();
      }

      /* load_container */

      function load_container() {

        if (position == (contents.length - 1)) {
          position = 0;
        } else {
          position++;
        }
        // Fade out the current item, replace it with the next one, and fade it in:
        if (opts.type == 'fade') {
          $('#news').fadeOut(opts.fade_speed, function() {
            $('#newscontent').html('<div id="news">' + contents[position] + '</div>');
            $('#news').fadeIn(opts.fade_speed);
          });
        }
        timer = setTimeout(load_container, opts.duration);
      }

      /* Control functions */

      $('a#pause_trigger').click(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(this).hide();
        $('#play_trigger').show();
        return false;
      });

      $('a#play_trigger').click(function() {
        load_container();
        $(this).hide();
        $('#pause_trigger').show();
        return false;
      });

      $('a#prev_trigger').click(function() {
        if (position == 0) {
          position = (contents.length - 1);
        } else {
          position--;
        }
        $('#newscontent').html('<div id="news" style="display:block">' + contents[position] + '</div>');
        if (opts.auto_stop) $('a#pause_trigger').trigger('click');
        return false;
      });

      $('a#next_trigger').click(function() {
        if (position == (contents.length - 1)) {
          position = 0;
        } else {
          position++;
        }
        $('#newscontent').html('<div id="news" style="display:block">' + contents[position] + '</div>');
        if (opts.auto_stop) $('a#pause_trigger').trigger('click');
        return false;
      });

    });

  };

  $.fn.tickerme.defaults = {
    fade_speed: 500,
    duration: 30000,
    auto_stop: true,
    type: 'fade',
    control_colour: '#333333',
    control_rollover: '#666666'
  };

}(jQuery));
$("div").tickerme();
```

```css
#ticker_wrap {
  margin: auto;
  width100%;
}

#ticker_container {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ticker_wrap">
  <div id="ticker">

    <div class="quotes">
      test 1
    </div>

    <div class="quotes">
      test 2
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As soon as your code uses `div id=` inside a loop, it's not going to work in more than one place.  Use classes and event delegation.  In addition `<a href="#"` is an anti-pattern - you should use `<button type=button` but that's not a problem as such.

Comment: so i change all div id to div class right?

Comment: In the first instance, yes.  But there are other considerations, such as eg  `$('a#pause_trigger').click(function() { .. $('#play_trigger').show();` couldn't be `$(".play_trigger")` otherwise it will show all play buttons - need to use the container, eg `$(this).closest(".controls").find(".play_trigger").show()`

Comment: Guess i will screw it all up :)

Comment: You'll be fine - as a hint, look at each line and consider "what if there are two (or more) of these".  Most of it can be fixed by using `var tickerControls = $(controls).insertAfter(ticker);` then you've got a reference to your controls (DOM/jquery) for this instance and can eg `tickerControls.find(".pause")`